# Dificuldade a entender "extends Application"

Tags: android

Boa noite, 
Estou com dificuldade de entender um exemplo

Vou tentar explicar sem postar o fonte inteiro acho que vai ser mais facil de entender

Tenho uma classe chamada GLOBAL que extends Application

dentro dela tenho 3 metodos

```
(...)
public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public boolean isAutenticado(){
    return getUsuario() != null;
}
(...)
```

Ai tenho uma classe modelo chamda

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String nome;

    public Usuario() {
        super();
    }

    public Usuario(String nome) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome == null ? "" : nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

Dentro da minha activety principal, tem algo muito sinistro

Bom ja vou falar que fiz a configuração no Manifest

```
(...)
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    iniciar();
    app = (MRCDroidAplicacao) getApplication();
}
(...)
```

ai que vem a zica, no exemplo do professor funciona, nesse meu que estou postando nao funciona

```
Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
usuario.setNome("USUARIO TESTE 1");
app.setUsuario(usuario);
Log.i("TESTE", "Usuario: " + app.getUsuario());
(...)
```

nao entendo o que estou fazendo por isso ta dificil UHEUHEUHE, estou copiando dele

Comment: Poderia informar qual o problema que ocorre? É normal ter uma classe que extende `Application`. Uma instância dessa classe fica disponível como o Contexto da aplicação (ela só é destruída quando o usuário deixa seu aplicativo), logo é normal guardar estado nela (salvo em momentos que o sistema fica com pouca memória).

Comment: Ola amigo, boa noite, O que acontece é: no log: Log.i("TESTE", "Usuario: " + app.getUsuario()); a saida é: 06-03 22:09:24.569: I/TESTE(2308): Usuario: br.com.mrcsistemas.mrcdroid.modelo.Usuario@b31c74f8 e eu estava esperando o nome de usuário logado pois tenho  a funcao public boolean isAutenticado(){
  return getUsuario() != null;
 }
que me retorna sempre falso

Comment: Na verdade, você precisa Logar dessa forma: `Log.i("TESTE", "Usuario: " + app.getUsuario.getNome());` ou sobreescrever o `toString` da classe `Usuario` para retornar o nome. Agora dependendo da ordem que está chamando o `isAutenticado`, ele deveria retornar `true`, porque o estado do usuário na instância do `Application`.

Comment: uhmm, perfeito, deu certo usar app.getUsuario.getNome()); mas como eu faria para ( app.setUsuario(usuario) ) e  depois isAutenticado() me retornar true

Comment: Você diz o `isAutenticado`? Poderia mostrar um caso mais completo de uso? Mostrando alguma ordem, porque me parece que é problema de concorrência, está acessando o  `isAutenticado` antes de setar o `usuario` nela.

Comment: poderia, mas eu nao entendi a logico do negocio: exemplo app.setUsuario(usuario); (como ele sabe que to passando o nome de usuario)

Comment: ublic void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
     if (user != null) {
      Usuario usuario = new Usuario(user.getFirstName());
      app.setUsuario(usuario);
      Log.i("TESTE", "Usuario: " + app.getUsuario().getNome());

     }
    }
   }).executeAsync();

   Log.i("teste", "autenticado" + app.isAutenticado());

Comment: Ah, agora faz sentido não funcionar... Vou criar uma resposta com base nisso, acho melhor que explicar por comentários.

Comment: :) muito agradeço,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O código que causa problema é justamente esse que postou:

```
(...)

    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
        if (user != null) {
            Usuario usuario = new Usuario(user.getFirstName());
            app.setUsuario(usuario);
            Log.i("TESTE", "Usuario: " + app.getUsuario().getNome());
        }
    }
}).executeAsync();

Log.i("teste", "autenticado" + app.isAutenticado());
```

Olhando esse código, está faltando um trecho importante, mas que dá pra adivinhar.

Esse trecho, que envolve o `onCompleted` está sendo executado de forma `assíncrona` (executeAsync), isso é, esta sendo executado em paralelo (possívelmente em uma Thread) com a linha seguinte `Log.i("teste", "autenticado" + app.isAutenticado());`.

O problema nesse caso é que a linha `Log.i("teste", "autenticado" + app.isAutenticado());` é **executada antes** de `app.setUsuario(usuario);`, justamente pelo paralelismo. Logo no momento que executa o `Log`, o usuário não está setado na instância da `Application`, por isso o valor `false`.

A recomendação seria migrar todo código que depende do usuário para dentro do `onCompleted`, desse modo:

```
(...)

    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
        if (user != null) {
            Usuario usuario = new Usuario(user.getFirstName());
            app.setUsuario(usuario);
            Log.i("TESTE", "Usuario: " + app.getUsuario().getNome());
            // .. Qualquer código que dependa do objeto setado no Application
            Log.i("teste", "autenticado" + app.isAutenticado());
        }
    }
}).executeAsync();
```

Pelo que deu pra ver das suas dúvidas, recomendo a leitura de dois "artigos": [orientacao-a-objetos-basica](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/orientacao-a-objetos-basica/#4-3-uma-classe-em-java) e [programacao-concorrente-e-threads](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/programacao-concorrente-e-threads/). Não estão muito relacionados com o problema principal citado, mas acho que deve ajudar a compreender todo esse código.

Comment: nss, realmente, e eu me matando, entendi o paralelismo sim. e obrigado pela diga de artigos, eu nao tenho um bom conhecimento em orientacao a objetos, eu vou meio que por rumo ctrl+c, vou ler os 2 sim, DEU CERTO, muito obrigado